# Я пишу небольшую игру но уже 2 раз сталкиваюсь с такой ошибкой

Tags: godot

Строка 13:`Cannot pass a value of type "String" as "int".`
Строка 13:`Invalid argument for "connect()" function: argument 3 should be "int" but is "String"`.

вот полный код:

```
extends Node

var game_scene

func _ready():
    # Загружаем сцену "Game"
    game_scene = load("res://Game.tscn").instance()
    # Добавляем сцену "Game" в дерево сцен
    add_child(game_scene)
    # Получаем ссылку на объект "Sign" в сцене "Game"
    var sign_node = game_scene.get_node("Sign")
    # Подключаем сигнал к методу объекта "Sign"
    connect("button_pressed", sign_node, "_on_button_pressed")

# Этот метод будет вызываться в сцене "UI", когда кнопка нажата
func emit_button_pressed(degrees: int):
    emit_signal("button_pressed", degrees)
```

Comment: Ну а в переводчик закинуть текст не судьба и прочитать?

Comment: неужели так сложно связать слово "connect" и "argument 3 should be "int"".....хоть немного можно же подумать